# how to call the method repaint() after a certain time

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, graphics, repaint

I  want to renew the toolTip so i thought in using the repaint method , to repaint the frame every 30 seconds but it doesn't work . can someone helpme..

GrphicsTut Method

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GrphicsTut extends JFrame{
    Timer timer; 
    Image image;
    Image image2;
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    Font fonte = new Font("TimesRoman ",Font.BOLD,100);

    public GrphicsTut(){
        MouseListenerJ bkg = new MouseListenerJ();
        this.setTitle("Remember g for Graphics");
        this.setSize(600,500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(bkg);
        this.addMouseListener(bkg);
        this.add(bkg);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics gr){ 
        gr.setFont(fonte);
        gr.setColor(Color.black);
        gr.drawLine(35,35, 410, 110);
        gr.drawLine(410,110, 310, 410);
        ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("image/1005511030.jpg");
        image=i.getImage();
        gr.drawImage(image, 35, 35,null);
        gr.drawImage(image, 400, 100,null);
        gr.drawImage(image, 300, 400,null);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GrphicsTut();
    }
}
```

and here the method for MouseListner

```
package Carte;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class MouseListenerJ extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    public MouseListenerJ(){}
    public void paint(Graphics g){}

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(me.getX()>=35 && me.getX()<=70 && me.getY()>=35 &&me.getY()<=70){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Que voulez vous faire");
            new Carte1();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Entered at x "+me.getX());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Exited"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Pressed at : "+me.getX()+" "+me.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("released");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(me.getX()>=35 && me.getX()<=70 && me.getY()>=35 && me.getY()<=70){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Que voulez vous faire");
            this.setToolTipText("text");
            System.out.println(me.getX()+"  "+me.getY());
        }
        else if(me.getX()>=400 && me.getX()<=470 && me.getY()>=100 && me.getY(<=170){
            this.setToolTipText("Text 2");
            System.out.println(me.getX()+"  "+me.getY());
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1) Consider telling us your original intent because this looks... awful 2) Never call repaint() within one of the paint() methods, this creates an infinite loop 3) always call super.paintXXX() in the paintXXX() methods 4) consider overriding paintComponent instead of paint() 5) Don't create an ImageIcon in your paint() method, instead create it upfront and reuse the same variable all the time (you could even make it a constant in this case)

Comment: thanks for answer. my objectif is to put some icones  in a graphic interface and then use mouseEvent to get ToolTips of those icones or to pass to other interface if i clic in it .

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the native Swing components for your objectives. They provide all the features you want:

- Handle mouse clicks
- Display tooltips
- Display images

Here is a small snippet showing you how to use `JButton`:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestButtons {

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 20, 20));
        panel.add(createButton("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000534649369/489a1e058bea59b62fd73c56f4bcb6c7.jpeg"));
        panel.add(createButton("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000714838591/ebbde1563faae6da2be79df945a7a02b.jpeg"));
        panel.add(createButton("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3477392906/f1907df0bd76668deac4a5e31a22fbe7.jpeg"));
        panel.add(createButton("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2718799802/9567ed3c3299f6f6ab1ffcbcbfd93da5.jpeg"));
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(final String url) throws MalformedURLException {
        final JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(new URL(url)));
        button.setToolTipText("You are looking at image located at " + url);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button,
                        "You clicked on image located at " + url);
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestButtons().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: the problem with this method is that i cant draw lines that's why i choosed to use Graphics in java. because i need something like a Map of some network equipement. [link](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_ccujEqzvArs/TEkRXpW4MmI/AAAAAAAAsDE/jsejvf-zJ6I/s1600/bgp-multipath-test.png)_italic_ **bold** `code`.

and when i hang the mouse over the image or the link (Line) it will show some information like IP Address, ports etc.

Comment: @aziz _the problem with this method is that i cant draw line_ ??? :-? ??? Let me just tell you my astonishment to that statement: 1) This is still perfectly possible. 2) Why not mention that in the first place?

Comment: Because when i draw an image with the methode drawImage (Graphics). i know exactly its coordinates. so i will use them to link two images by using drawLine(x1,y1, x2,y2). but in this case you used a GridLayout .. (or other).. this is an 
[Example](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_ccujEqzvArs/TEkRXpW4MmI/AAAAAAAAsDE/jsejvf-zJ6I/s1600/bgp-multipath-test.png) of what i want to Draw. 
(I mentioned it in my last comment )

Why not mention that in the first place : because my problem is with the method repaint ( I want to do it my self to learn ;) )
 thank you.

Comment: @Aziz You can perfectly find the coordinates of your images, you just need to store the buttons somewhere and then simply wuery `button.getBounds()`. You can then decide to override the `paint()` method of the `panel` and draw the lines after calling `super.paint()` (this will ensure that you actually draw over the child buttons).